# How to wrap paper around an object?

Tags: modeling, workflow, cloth-simulation, geometry, photorealism

I'm new in Blender and I'm making a jar bottle to start and want to close the top wraping with paper like these ones:

[image]

I tried using cloth modifier with a colision object + pressure but I can't find a way to make those folds in the paper like you can see in the picture. I already checked a lot of tutorials and questions but didn't find anything useful to get those folds.

That's the best I get out of it:

[image]

**Q:** Any other idea how to achieve that kind of folds as realistic as possible?

Comment: You choose the most complicated thing. I dont think there is an fastest way than to model manually and use normal maps for details. Paper is very specific material. I did few years back wrapping box with armature https://vimeo.com/user8735075, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Try adding a few creases before you run the cloth simulation... check this video... https://youtu.be/Jj5nXcq7enQ

Comment: 1st do a cloth simulation and then a shrinkwrap.

Comment: tried the shrinkwrap after the cloth simulation but i get weird poligons (tried increasing the subdivisions but don't get the result that i want)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Cloth Sim

- Add Circle 16 sides, Extrude, Scale, Grid Fill
- Extrude, Scale outer loop, select vertices for each side and Scale on (X/Y) to zero to get square shape, add extra loops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

[image]

- Add cloth simulation (physics)
- Add ShrinkWrap modifier, select one vertex loop next to perfect circles and assign vertex group to these, and use this group for modifier
- The illusion that brings cloth more to paper feeling is under *Data Properties > Normal >* **Auto Smooth**

[image]

- To add detail to the lowpoly simulated mesh just add a **Normal Map** texture of smashed paper

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Notes:**

- Select outer loop and with *Proportional editing* (O) rotate (R) a bit, twisted topology results in nicer sim
- With a few extra loops close to existing folding is a bit closer to your reference.

[image]

- To let border of paper stick closer to glass you can create another vertex group and use second Shrink-wrap modifier with a subtle Ofset value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Funny, the *best quality answer* only has one up-vote (mine). Good example that peps here are just lazy to vote or having a hard time understanding/trying out a more complex setup than using a cheap array modifier for all sort of things. Anyway, nice answer!

Comment: sorry for my delay in my answer, incredible result. Don't know the words in english to regards you about this method (masterclass). I'll try this weekend and let you know the result  : ).

Comment: @brockmann I'm sure folks will come back to this really nice answer for reference in the future: its score will grow  over time.

Comment: alrteady tried, i need to perfect a little the glass now (many polygons so i got some weird points but i fixed manually after apply the modifiers) anyways i'll redo the model to make the cloth simulation more easy to do but it's nearly like the real one that i use for reference with your method.
Do you have some patreon or a paypal? with your explanation i learn a lot of useful tips (the grid fill is a great discovery). Didn't find a way to add a picture to this post to show the result but it's nearly perfect. Once again don't know words enough to thank you for this tutorial

Comment: @Tomas Great it's helpful for you :)  You asked interesting question, so ... thanks too :)

Comment: @JachymMichal WHAT??? Ehm ... do you have an empty pantry already? The jam has run out and this is your way of order? I hope your life is going well and this is not your inheritance given to a community :) Because I saw another high score at Fork yesterday. What is going on here man?

Comment: @vklidu Sorry I missed your comment before, [SE didn't ping me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131372/652639) :). The answer's top notch, you're gaining a rep here as an expert on simulations. Enjoy the internet points, you can't buy beer with them anyways :).

Answer (score 10):

You could eyeball it using *Subdivision modifier* and some sculpting.
Once you figure out the crease shape it works kinda nice.

<sup>*Pickled Suzanne, 1889. Delicious.*</sup>
[image]

1. Start with a subdivided plane roughly the shape of the crease
   <sub>(The shape is kinda hard to describe, it's basically an S shaped plane)</sub>
2. Add Array modifier
   <sub>(Or model the other creases manually)</sub>
3. Add *Simple deform Modifier* set to Bend, Angle 360°
4. Add a *Weld modifier* and *Subdivision modifier* to smoothen the shape

[image]

Comment: please could you add a link to suzanne delicious vendor site? ; )

Comment: Found them in the pantry, granny used to put them on everything! :))

Comment: nice! but is 1889 the year it has been canned?

Comment: @moonboots I'd say so! Pairs perfectly with the 1886 LaTour... and works wonders for removing rust.

Comment: lol, that's great

Comment: wow, that's nice i'll give a try!.thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

This example you posted I believe is likely done by sculpting but simulation may be faster here (for multiple good looking results with low experience. *There were many major advances in the last year(s) of Blender development that are worth checking out if you aim for speed.*

### Sculpting method

The steps you take and the ways you sculpt is completely up to you here.
In *Blender 2.80+* you...

1. Select the cloth (In object mode (switch with <kbd>TAB</kbd> or dropdown menu in the upper left corner of 3D viewport)
2. Go to "Sculpting" workspace (at the top of the UI)
3. Sculpt the surface to your liking. (with tools on the left - toggle by <kbd>T</kbd>, (<kbd>NUM /</kbd> to isolate selected object)

For older versions refer to Blender Wiki (Docs) [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/).

For basic and traditional sculpting I'd recommend starting with official Blender guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAGWu08oWAM) and seeing sculpting walkthroughs in Blender and other software too (you can very well refer in this topic).

For cloth tool sculpting (new, faster) [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjPbZBAApUI) might help you start.

### Simulation method

By creating **any shape(s) (mesh)** for the cloth to collide against (e.g. during a fall) without making the collision shape(s) visible, you can create many seemingly random and beautiful folds and wrinkles.

I recommend seeing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5GFtJPvQXo) short video for guidance (different scenario, same base method)